# Starfield canvas program takes up too much CPU

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cpu-usage

I have created a starfield using `canvas` and it works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>StarField</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="startGame()"></body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var NO_OF_STARS = 512;
        var stars = [];

        function startGame() {          
            gameArea.start(); /* Makes the canvas */

            gameRun = requestAnimationFrame(gameArea.update); /* Starts the game and coordinates all the animations */

            window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 27) { /* ESC stops everything */
                    stopEverything();
                }
            });
        }

        var gameArea = {
            canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
            start : function() {
                document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

                this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
                this.canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
            },
            update : function() {               
                gameArea.clear(); /* Fills the canvas with #000000 */
                gameArea.drawStars(); /* Draws the stars */

                gameRun = requestAnimationFrame(gameArea.update); /* Repeat the whole thing */
            },
            drawStars : function() {
                var ctx = gameArea.canvas.getContext("2d");

                if(stars.length == 0) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < NO_OF_STARS; i++) {
                        var opacity = ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) / 10) + .1);

                        stars.push([getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.width - 1), getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.height - 1),opacity]);

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + opacity + ")";
                        ctx.moveTo(stars[i][0], stars[i][1]);
                        ctx.lineTo(stars[i][0] + 1, stars[i][1] + 1);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                } else {
                    for(var i = 0; i < NO_OF_STARS; i++) {
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + stars[i][2] + ")";

                        stars[i][0] -= ((stars[i][2] == 1.0) ? 5 :
                                        (stars[i][2] >= 0.8) ? 4 :
                                        (stars[i][2] >= 0.5) ? 3 :
                                        (stars[i][2] >= 0.3) ? 2 :
                                                               1);

                        if(stars[i][0] < 0) {
                            var opacity = ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) / 10) + .1);
                            stars.splice(i, 1, [gameArea.canvas.width, getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.height - 1), opacity]);
                        }

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(stars[i][0], stars[i][1]);
                        ctx.lineTo(stars[i][0] + 1, stars[i][1] + 1);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                }
            },
            clear : function() {
                var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            }
        };

        /**
         * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
         */
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        function stopEverything() {
            cancelAnimationFrame(gameRun);
        }

    </script>

</html>
```

**The problem here is that it takes up lots of CPU** (60% to 65% on a laptop having an AMD A8 quad-core processor). I want this canvas program to run in other computers having low-end processors too.

I've tried reducing the `NO_OF_STARS` but this doesn't change the CPU usage. When increasing it however, the animation gets slowed down considerably and the CPU usuage is reduced (I don't think I'll be increasing it though, so this is not really relevant)

I've also noticed that the size of the canvas plays a significant role in the CPU usage. (The laptop I mentioned above has a resolution of 1366x768) But I want the canvas to take the full viewport.

So, How do I reduce the CPU usage?

Comment: Can someone please edit that code into a stack snippet? I'm on mobile and stack snippets aren't supported by touch devices...

Comment: Did you try running a cpu profiler on your code? It might help you identify where the cpu intensive parts are. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Answer (score 2):

It's quite expensive to define a path, stroke style and rasterize it for each star. Try to collect some operations to reduce the load - it's all about making compromises:

- Choose 3-5 pre-defined opacity levels
- Draw number of stars divided on number of pre-defined opacity levels
- Use a single beginPath() before loop
- Use rect() instead of moveTo+LineTo
- fill() once after the loop finishes, continue with the next opacity level
- Obtain 3D context once, not per call
- Use integer values for the star positions (forces an integer step, perhaps not ideal in this case but worth a try)
- Recycle/reuse star entries instead of splicing and creating new ones
- Reduce number of calculations and conditions where you can
- Reduce frame rate to 30 FPS (toggle RAF to draw every other time). 60 FPS is nice, but we'll get away with 30 FPS too like movies (though, they benefits from motion blur; we can cheat by using sprites with embedded "motion blur" instead of drawing rectangles).
- Optionally: store each field layer as a separate canvas, draw in as image (faster, but requires more memory). Variations can be made by tiling the canvas rotated and/or flipped.

I would personally hardcode the opacity levels, but I left the adjusted code below with random generation (hit run button several times).

Typically you would still get some hit on the CPU/GPU but these tips should improve performance (or in this case reduce the load).

```js
var NO_OF_STARS = 500; // divisable by 5 (due to num. of opacities - see below)
var stars = [];

function startGame() {
  gameArea.start(); /* Makes the canvas */

  gameRun = requestAnimationFrame(gameArea.update); /* Starts the game and coordinates all the animations */

  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { /* ESC stops everything */
      stopEverything();
    }
  });
}

var gameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  ctx: null,
  opacities: [],
  start: function() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

    this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

    // store context once
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // opacity levels
    for (var t = 0; t < 5; t++) this.opacities.push(((Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) / 10) + .1));

  },
  update: function() {
    gameArea.clear(); /* Fills the canvas with #000000 */
    gameArea.drawStars(); /* Draws the stars */

    gameRun = requestAnimationFrame(gameArea.update); /* Repeat the whole thing */
  },

  drawStars: function() {
    var ctx = this.ctx;

    if (!stars.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < NO_OF_STARS; i++) {
        stars.push({
          x: getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.width - 1)|0, 
          y: getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.height - 1)|0
        });
      }
    }

    for (t = 0, pos = 0; t < 5; t++) {
      var opacity = this.opacities[t];
      ctx.beginPath();

      for (var i = 0; i < NO_OF_STARS / 5; i++) {
        
        stars[pos].x -= opacity * opacity * 4;

        if (stars[pos].x < 0) {
          stars[pos].x = gameArea.canvas.width;
          stars[pos].y = getRandomInt(0, gameArea.canvas.height - 1)|0;
        }

        ctx.rect(stars[pos].x, stars[pos].y, 1, 1);
        pos++;  // total position
      }

      ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + opacity + ")";
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  },
  clear: function() {
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
};

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function stopEverything() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(gameRun);
}

startGame();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```